# Not able to configure WMI Connection for remote server

Tags: ssis, wmi

I am trying to configure an SSIS package to read values(like disc free space and total space) from remote server. For which i need to configure WMI Connection manager.

I have entered IP address (\\ip address\) of the server in "Server Name:" text box and user credentials for this server. When i try to Test the connection by clicking on Test button, it gives me the message:

*Failed to connect to the specified server with the following message: "User credentials can not be used for local connections". The server name may be invalid.*

Comment: Is the remote machine in same domain as your machine? Try prefixing the IP address with \\

Comment: yes...both machines are on same domain. I am already using \\ before IP address. I have modified my question with the same.

Comment: I have also tried by removing \ from the end of ip address, still no luck.

Comment: Have you checked what is the namespace you are passing? And can you try with Windows authentication instead of user name password?

Comment: I tried by using windows authentication, it works fine. But I have a different issue now. I have two WMI Data Reader tasks to pull details from two different servers. I am dumping the details from both tasks to a single file by appending. The problem is both the tasks return same results even though they are pointing at different servers.

Comment: It seems that in both the scenarios, task is returning the details for local machine rather than remote server.